# Why some method's doc string shows up in Spyder but not others?

Tags: pyspark, namespaces, spyder, python-module, python-packaging

I have module `pyspark.sql.functions` loaded:

```
>>> sys.modules['pyspark.sql.functions']
<module 'pyspark.sql.functions' from 'C:\\Users\\User.Name\\anaconda3\\envs\\py39\\lib\\site-packages\\pyspark\\sql\\functions.py'>
```

I can pull up the doc string for (say) method `avg`, but not `grouping`:

```
>>> sys.modules['pyspark.sql.functions'].avg?
Signature: avg(col: 'ColumnOrName') -> pyspark.sql.column.Column
Docstring:
Aggregate function: returns the average of the values in a group.
<...snip...>

>>> sys.modules['pyspark.sql.functions'].grouping?
Object `grouping` not found.
```

I see that both are defined in `functions.py`.  Why would the doc string for `avg` be findable but not for `grouping`?

**P.S.** Even without the answer as to why, it would be helpful to have corroboration on this observed behaviour.  Thanks.  My Spark version is 3.4.1 and Python version is 3.9.  My packages are set up using Anaconda's package manager.

**2023-10-24 afternote:** I had to restart my Spyder session and
ended up exploring `grouping()` instead of `avg()`:

```
# Did this
from pyspark.sql.functions import grouping

# Didn't do this
# from pyspark.sql.functions import avg
```

The above was the *reverse* of what I did in posting the question.
Consequently, I had the *reverse* problem, i.e.,
`sys.modules["pyspark.sql.functions"].grouping?` pulls up a doc string
in Spyder, but `sys.modules["pyspark.sql.functions"].avg?` finds
nothing.

This tells me that even though *all* of `pyspark/sql/functions.py` is
executed, not all of the objects created are bound to corresponding
names in the `pyspark.sql.functions` namespace.  Only the specific objects named in the `import` command are.

I'm confused by this.  I understand that first `import` above
only binds the `grouping` method to the name `grouping` in the
current (REPL) namespace, but why would it also *not* bind the other
objects to their corresponding names in the
`pyspark.sql.functions` namespace?  The latter is supposed to be
the entire module.

If the designed-for behaviour is in fact to *not* bind the other
objects in the `functions` module to their names in
`sys.modules["pyspark.sql.functions"]`, then what is the point of
maintaining the latter namespace?

Comment: Which version of spark are you on?

Comment: The Spark version is 3.4.1